# Outlined Text Field for TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to create a TextInputLayout with Outline Boarder. But whenever I use the,following style, it malfunction(crash) the app.

Before posting I have tried every solution that listed in and outside the stackoverflow, but nothing fixed the issue so far.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

**Current layout**

```
<ScrollView...

    <LinearLayout
      android: layout_width = "200dp"
      android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
      android: orientation = "vertical"
      android: layout_marginTop = "2dp" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       android: id = "@+id/outlinedTextField"
       android: layout_width = "match_parent"
       android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
       android: hint = "@string/label"
       style = "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
       app: boxStrokeWidthFocused = "2dp"
       app: boxStrokeColor = "@color/border_primary" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android: layout_width = "match_parent"
       android: layout_height = "wrap_content" />
    
  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Complete Layout:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".user.userprofile.UserProfileFragment">
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <include layout="@layout/user_profile_header"/>
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android: hint = "@string/label"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/text_primary"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/text_primary"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/border_primary">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </ScrollView>
```

More Info : when `style` is added `hint` goes out of focus. Also border doesn't appear.

Comment: Hey @Rootster , I do not know what specifically you meant when you said malfunction but, `TextInputEditText` is meant to be used inside of `TextInputEditText`. please paste in your full xml and  what exactly is your malfunction. Maybe I can help

Comment: It's indeed neccesarry to know what the exact "malfunction" is. And @ravi means that `TextInputEditText` must be inside `TextInputLayout` (he made a small typo)

Comment: malfunction as in app crashes everytime when i start it. but when i remove the 
`style = "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`it works fine. Also i would like to add when I use the above style, "hint" also goes out of focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check a couple of things:

1. Make sure that your `AppTheme` is a child of
   `Theme.MaterialComponents` (or a descendant).

So, your style.xml should be something like

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
         <!-- rest of your style items-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

2. You add the material components library in module gradle file

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'`

Comment: current gradle version `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

Comment: @Rooster No problem whether version you use, just make sure you add it

Comment: i have checked my AppTheme in style. I have something like this. 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

could you please share me how it should look like with `Theme.MaterialComponents`

Comment: Your ```AppTheme's parent``` is set ```AppCompat```. Since you're using ```Material Components```, set the parent to ```Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar```

Comment: It worked!!! Both of you, really thank you! with this, Zain you fixed my most painful problem, and Dev, you fixed the other. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 4):

`TextInputLayout` is not a self closing tag.
Edit your code and enclose `TextInputEditText`  within `TextInputLayout`..

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android: hint = "@string/label"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/text_primary"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/text_primary"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/border_primary">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @Hi Dev this is right, but the poster already added that their app launches when they remove `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`.. I think this is just a typo in their post

Comment: yeah that is a typo. sorry about that. it's not in the actual code. i will fix it in the question